# How do I copy column from one workbook to the another?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to copy complete column of an excel into a different excel. Is there any API which can do this in python pandas?

I tried the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df1=pd.read_excel('C:\Python_Pandas\Tested_2\Excel_1.xlsx',sheet_name=0,usecols='A,B')
print(df1.columns)

df2=pd.read_excel('C:\Python_Pandas\Tested_2\Excel_2.xlsx',sheet_name=0,usecols='A,B')
print(df2.columns)
```

`excel_1` and `excel_2` has `3` columns. `A`,`B` and `C`.
Now my goal is to copy data in column `B` of `excel_1` to column `C` of `excel_2`. How can we do that using python pandas?

Comment: I do not work with python pandas but can definitely read code to some extent which is [available online](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-move-data-from-one-excel-file-to-another-using-python-a513491234f4) **1.** Where are you copying and pasting? `print(df)` will only output the result in the *integrated terminal* below the script. **2.** I would recommend going through the link that I gave and see if it helps?

Comment: If each file has data in columns A, B and C why are you only reading columns A and B?

Comment: I only need those columns for my next steps so i am only using those @norie

Comment: thanks for the link @SiddharthRout , I have looked into it but it dint complete my goal I am looking for.